# how do i check whether these vectors are linearly dependent or independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

In fact, an n-dimensional space can have as many as n linearly independent vectors. The following three vectors are three dimensional, which means that we must check if they are linearly dependent or independent.

Are the following vectors linearly independent?

$\mathbf{a} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},
 \mathbf{b} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},
 \mathbf{c} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
$

Comment: Can you find a non-trivial solution of $c_1{\bf a}+c_2{\bf b}+c_3{\bf c}=\bf 0$?

Comment: all are a,b,c=0 so are they dependent ?

Comment: You mean, each of $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$ must be zero. So, they are independent. Your vectors are independent if and only if the only solution of   $c_1{\bf a}+c_2{\bf b}+c_3{\bf c}=\bf 0$ is the trivial (all $c-i=0$) solution. This is the definition of "independent".

Answer (score 1):

Solve the system
$$\alpha+\beta+\gamma=0$$
$$\beta=0$$
$$\gamma=0$$
for $$\alpha,\beta,\gamma$$

Comment: so they are dependent right ?

Comment: The only solution is given by $$\alpha=\beta=\gamma=0$$ so they are independent

Answer (score 1):

The three vectors are linearly independent iff the equation system 
$$1x + 1y + 1z = 0 \\
0x + 1y + 0z = 0 \\
0x + 0y + 1z = 0$$

yields $x=y=z=0$, which - in this case - is true and so the three vectors are in fact linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

$n$ vectors in  $\mathbb {R} ^{n}$ are linearly independent if and only if the [determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence#Alternative_method_using_determinants) of the matrix formed by taking the vectors as its columns is non-zero.  Since in this case the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$is upper triangular, it is easy to evaluate its determinant.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine this pretty quickly by inspection. Since $\mathbf c$ is the only one with a nonzero third component, its coefficient in the linear combination $c_1\mathbf a+c_2\mathbf b+c_3\mathbf c=\mathbf 0$ must be zero. Similarly, the coefficient of $\mathbf b$ must be zero, and that leaves $\mathbf a$ as the only vector that can contribute to the first component of the sum, so its coefficient, too, must be zero.