# Determine for what values of $\alpha$, $Gen${$(0, 1, \alpha), (\alpha, 1, 0), (0, \alpha, 1)$}$=\Bbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that for the given set generates $\Bbb R^3$, every element of $\Bbb R^3$ must be written as a linear combination of the vectors. But if I take any element $(a, b, c) \in \Bbb R^3$, I get a system with four unknown quantities: $a, b, c, \alpha$. So, I must to take a particular element, for instance, $(1, 1, 1)$ or $(0, 0, 0)$?
(I cannot use anything about basis)
I would really appreciate your help, any hint.

Comment: Note that if $\alpha=0$ then the first two are the same, if $\alpha=1$ the first and last are, and if $\alpha=-1$ the last is a multiple of the first.  Do you know about determinants?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner The determinant of the matrix is $\alpha (\alpha - 1)(\alpha +1)$. So $\alpha$ can be any value except roots of the equation?

Comment: Yes, $n$ vectors in $\mathbb {R} ^{n}$ are linearly independent if and only if the determinant of the matrix formed by taking the vectors as its columns is non-zero; cf. my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3477355)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do i check whether these vectors are linearly dependent or independent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3477345/how-do-i-check-whether-these-vectors-are-linearly-dependent-or-independent)

Comment: Have you studied about rank of a matrix? You want the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0&\alpha & 0\\ 1&1&\alpha \\ \alpha & 0& 1\end{pmatrix}\tag*{}$ to have a rank of $3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimension of $\mathbb{R}^3$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is $3$. This is because dimension is defined as the number of elements in the basis, and there are precisely $3$ elements in any basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. You say that you don't want to use anything about basis in your answer, so here we go.

The given set of three elements will generate the whole of $\mathbb{R}^3$ if the elements in the set are linearly independent. (In fact, thus the three vectors will form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$). Now, how do you check for linear independence? Here's a series of equivalent statements:

Form a matrix by arranging the vectors row-wise.

The vectors will be linearly independent $\iff$ the rows of the matrix are linearly independent $\iff$ The row-reduced echelon form of the matrix has no zero rows $\iff$ The matrix is invertible $\iff$ The determinant of the matrix is non-zero.

I'll leave the final steps to you. If you do not know determinants yet (in a standard Linear Algebra course, determinant comes into play much later), row-reduce the matrix and check for what values of $\alpha$ it is not invertible. $\alpha$ cannot take those values in $\mathbb{R}$.

**Hint:** The answer is, $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{-1, 0, 1\}$